# how to pass large data to service layer using wcf service?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, file-upload

I am trying to implement attachment functionality in one of my web application. It has three layer. Presentation, Business and Service Layer and i have blob datatype in database of attachment field....i am getting below Error while transferring data from business layer to service layer.

```
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request
```

I cant find any solution even i tried with increase arraylength, buffersize etc...But still getting error...So if anyone have any idea than please help me....I am facing this issue since 5 days.....

Here is my web.config settings

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITestService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="83886080" maxBufferPoolSize="83886080" maxReceivedMessageSize="83886080"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
```

Answer (score 0):

turn on WCF tracing on server side by adding following section to WCF host's configuration file. you will be able to get more specific reason for your failure from the trace file.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false"/>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="sdt" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\temp\ServiceTrace.svclog"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use WCF streaming for the purpose of uploading large files. But still there are some limits for the approach being used. So transferring large files over HTTP needs a lot of considerations.
Detailed examples and consideration has been posted already at following links.

1. http://garfoot.com/blog/2008/06/transferring-large-files-using-wcf/
2. http://kjellsj.blogspot.com/2007/02/wcf-streaming-upload-files-over-http.html

Answer (score 0):

> need to use WCF streaming for the purpose of uploading large files. But still there are some limits for the approach being used. So transferring large files over HTTP needs a lot of considerations. Detailed examples and consideration has been posted already at following links.  http://garfoot.com/blog/2008/06/transferring-large-files-using-wcf/
>   http://kjellsj.blogspot.com/2007/02/wcf-streaming-upload-files-over-http.html